# dynamic typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I have a typedef inside a class from a c++ machine library (dlib) that looks like this:

```
typedef dlib::matrix<double, 64, 1> sample_type;
```

Except the 64 is actually a variable.  I'd like the typedef to be visible throughout the class, but I want the second parameter (the 64) be an argument when the constructor is called.  How can I achieve this, while keeping the typedef visible everywhere?

Comment: To expand on @R.MartinhoFernandes' comment: template expansion happens at compile time, so template parameters must be constants known at compile time.

Comment: why not just make a helper function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general case this is not possible. Although you might want to write the following:

```
template <int matrix_size>
struct sample_type : public dlib::matrix<double, matrix_size, 1>
{
    sample_type data1;
    sample_type<16> data2;
};

sampe_type<32> var32;
sampe_type<36> var36;
```

Note that inside the template 2 data fields are defined. The first data field will be created with the current instantiation parameter. Second data field will be created using explicit parameter.

As you see, inside the template it seems to be what you want, but outside only constants can be used.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible with the current design because template parameters **must** be known at compile time while a constructor's arguments do not have that restriction.

The reason for this is because any template expansion should be seen as it's own type; the template parameter is part of the type (`std::vector<int>` is a different type than `std::vector<float>`).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually one of the [frequently asked questions](http://dlib.net/faq.html#How%20do%20I%20set%20the%20size%20of%20a%20matrix%20at%20runtime?) on the dlib web page.  What you do is this:

```
typedef dlib::matrix<double, 0, 1> sample_type;
sample_type myvect(64); // now the 64 is a runtime argument.
```